# linq select clause syntax

Tags: linq, select, syntax

Linq Select method takes Func as input parameter. This means I can have multiple statements in selector for Select, such as

```
var myresult = sources.Select(s => 
     {int x; if (s.val = high) {x=1} else if (s.val = med) {x=2} else {x=3}; return x;
     }
  )
```

How can I do this using Linq query syntax

```
var myresult = from s in sources
       select ...
```

Here, the code in Func part (if ... else if .. else) is artificial. What I really want to know is the syntax of select clause, which may be described as

```
select select-expression
```

What is the syntax of

> select-expression

Comment: Microsoft published 101 LINQ samples via the MSDN. The [Projection Operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825) are what you are after which include Select.

Comment: `if (s.val = high)` is wrong because it does an assignment, not an equality check.  Did you mean `if (s.val == high)`?  Also, I'd use an enum instead of magic numbers (`x = SomeEnum.High` instead of `x = 1`).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't want to see your first version in my code. If you need to have what is basically a full function in the lambda, I would rather see the lambda simply invoke a full function! In other words...

```
theQuery.Select(s => GetX(s)); // just define a GetX function
```

And that would also be a straightforward translation to query expression syntax

```
from s in sources
select GetX(s);
```

You would not be able to put your full code block into the query expression syntax. You could translate your given logic to something usable (yet messy), however I'm quite sure your snippet is just a general example. On the offhand change it isn't, you might try

```
select s.val == high ? 1 : (s.val == med ? 2 : 3); // totally messy
```

Comment: I would rather create a delegate from the method itself than from a lambda expression that calls the method, i.e. `theQuery.Select(GetX);`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer. My real question is what is the syntax of select clause? I can describe it as <br/> <pre><code> select select-expression  What is select-expression?

Comment: @hshen: A `select-expression` is an expression that, when evaluated, returns a value.  Give a function with the signature `int GetX(WhateverTypeSIs s)`, you could have `GetX(s)` as a valid `select-expression`.  The code sample in the middle shows you exactly what you asked for...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

If you really want to, you could create an `Func<T>` from an anonymous method and invoke it, but that would be horrible.

Comment: Why would it be horrible?  I don't like the `if ... else if ... ` code, but I do like using named local delegates, and I see nothing wrong with using them in Linq when appropriate.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I don't mean a local named delegate.  I mean `select new Func<T>(delegate { ... })()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of special-casing values, with the `if/else` equivalent of a `switch` statement, it is more Linq-friendly to group and filter your values:

```
var myResult = from s in sources
               group by s.val into g
               select new { Val = g.Key, Sources = g };

var groupHigh = myResult.Where(i => i.Val == high);
var groupMedium = myResult.Where(i => i.Val == medium);
var groupOther = myResult.Except(groupHigh.Concat(groupMedium));
```

Note that the code I've provided is just a starting place, and isn't the best way to achieve your specific goal.  I'd address this in one of these ways:

- Change how `group by` is used (use `SomeFunction(s.Val)` instead of directly using `s.Val`)
- Change the code around this query to flow better with the natural groupings, so I didn't require the groups to be transformed

Answer (score 0):

MSDN indicates **select** is a contextual keyword of C# 4.0. So I checked the C# Language Specififcation 4.0. Its **Select clauses** section (7.16.2.5) specifies that

> A query expression of the form
>   `from x in e select v`
>   is translated into
>   `( e ) . Select ( x => v )`
>   except when v is the identifier x, the translation is simply
>   `( e )`

As the result, the syntax for

> select select-expresion

**select-expression** should be anything that can be used as TResult in **Select** Method. So the functionality can be done using anonymous Func in **Select** method may not be able to achieved using **select clause**.

Conclusion is that you should stick with Method syntax as this is how the code really runs behind the scene.

Comment: Your conclusion is not helpful. The conclusion should be that you should use the form that allows you to best express what you are trying to accomplish. Sometimes, the full query expression syntax is going to be more readable. Sometimes the lambda or fluent syntax will be what you need. Don't let *what the compiler turns it into* determine *what you write.* If you were to follow your argument, you would not write in C#, but rather IL, as that's what the compiler turns it into. Of course, then you would write your IL into machine language, as that's what happens to the IL. And so on.

Comment: Further following your logic, you wouldn't do a lot of the things you write, because the compiler turns it into something else (even before going to IL). You wouldn't use a foreach loop, you wouldn't use anonymous types, you wouldn't use the keyword `var`. The compiler gets rid of all of it.